# ColdFusion using if conditional inside a script based cfc function

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm trying to get better at my cfscript and can't figure this one out.  In a tag based CFC I could do something like this:

```
<cffunction name="querySd" access="public" returnType="query" output="false">
  <cfargument name="sd_id" type="numeric" required="No"/>
  <cfargument name="sd_code" type="string" required="No"/>
  <cfquery name="LOCAL.qrySd" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
    SELECT sd_id, sd_code, sd_active, sd_expires, sd_added, sd_dla
     FROM sd 
    WHERE 0=0
     <cfif isDefined("ARGUMENTS.sd_id")>
       AND sd_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ARGUMENTS.sd_id#"/>
     </cfif>
     <cfif isDefined("ARGUMENTS.sd_code")>
      AND sd_code = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#ARGUMENTS.sd_code#" maxlength="20"/>
     </cfif>
    </cfquery>
  <cfreturn LOCAL.qrySd>
</cffunction>
```

However, trying a similar method in cfscript throws an error:

```
public query function querySd( numeric sd_id, string sd_code ){
  local.querySd = new Query(datasource = variables.dsn);
  if( isDefined('arguments.sd_id') ){
    local.querySd.addParam( name = 'sdid', value = arguments.sd_id, cfsqltype = 'cf_sql_int');
  };
  if( isDefined('arguments.sd_code') ){
    local.querySd.addParam( name = 'sdcode', value = arguments.sd_code, cfsqltype = 'cf_sql_varchar', maxlength = '20');
  };

 local.querySd.setSql('
            SELECT sd_id, sd_code, sd_active, sd_expires, sd_added, sd_dla
              FROM sd
             WHERE 0 = 0
             if( isDefined('arguments.sd_id') ){
                 AND sd_id = :sdid 
             };
             if( isDefined('arguments.sd_code') ){
                 AND sd_code = :sdcode 
             };
        ');
local.qrySd = local.querySd.execute().getResult();
```

What's the correct way of working with optional arguments in a cfscript based query inside of a cfc?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but structKeyExist is usually preferred over IsDefined, for better precision.

Comment: Good point - code updated - thanks!

Comment: What version of CF?

Comment: OT: If I was converting, I would use queryexecute(). It has a simpler syntax.

Comment: Ditto on using queryExecute over the older Query.cfc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said, depending on the CF version you are using, I'd use `queryExecute()` over `new Query()`. There are many reasons why, and that is pretty much a whole other topic in and of itself.

Anyway, now that I have a minute, I've thrown together an example of `queryExecute()` for completeness. *NOTE: I am using a query of query against mocked data here. The real query would use an actual datasource.*

```
<cfscript>
public Query function querySd2 ( Numeric sd_id, String sd_code ) {
    // This is my fake query data, thanks to Mockaroo.
    local.sd = queryNew("sd_id,sd_code,sd_active,sd_expires,sd_added,sd_dla",
    "integer,varchar,bit,date,date,varchar",
    [ 
        { "sd_id":1,"sd_code":"DontPickMe","sd_active":true,"sd_expires":"2019-01-04","sd_added":"2018-05-07","sd_dla":"2M66CAf3" } ,
        { "sd_id":2,"sd_code":"PickMe","sd_active":true,"sd_expires":"2018-03-03","sd_added":"2018-08-18","sd_dla":"8FW4HRm8" } ,
        { "sd_id":3,"sd_code":"DontPickMe","sd_active":true,"sd_expires":"2019-01-01","sd_added":"2018-10-28","sd_dla":"4F6kBUm2" } ,
        { "sd_id":4,"sd_code":"PickMe","sd_active":false,"sd_expires":"2018-10-28","sd_added":"2018-08-22","sd_dla":"2NSlNLr8" } ,
        { "sd_id":5,"sd_code":"DontPickMe","sd_active":false,"sd_expires":"2018-03-07","sd_added":"2019-02-09","sd_dla":"8T0cWQc2" }
    ]);
    ////////////////

    local.sqlWhere = "1=1" ; // This is our default WHERE condition.
    local.qryParams  = {} ;  // queryExecute expects a struct of params. Or an array.

    // First, I check that the given args have a length, then create both 
    // the SQL and the param. Also "?." is the safe-navigation operator, added
    // in CF2016. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/using/language-enhancements.html
    if( len(trim(arguments?.sd_id)) ) {
        sqlWHERE &= " AND sd_id = :sdid" ;  // This is our SQL string. 
        qryParams.sdid = { value:arguments.sd_id, cfsqltype:"cf_sql_integer" } ;
    }

    if( len(trim(arguments?.sd_code)) ) {
        sqlWHERE &= " AND sd_code = :sdcode" ;
        qryParams.sdcode = { value:arguments.sd_code, cfsqltype:"cf_sql_varchar", maxlength:"20" }  ;
    }

    //writeDump(sqlWhere) ;

    // https://cfdocs.org/queryexecute
    local.qrySd = queryExecute( 
          "SELECT sd_id, sd_code, sd_active, sd_expires, sd_added, sd_dla FROM sd WHERE #sqlWhere#" 
        , qryParams 
        , { dbtype="query"} //datasource="dsn" } // Replace dbtype with datasource.
    ) ;
    return qrySd ;  // return our query object.
}

// TESTS
tests = [
    {qry:querySd2(2,"PickMe")         , label:"Results from query"                 , retval:querySd2(2,"PickMe").sd_expires } ,
    {qry:querySd2(1,"PickMe")         , label:"No Results from query"              , retval:querySd2(1,"PickMe").sd_expires } ,
    {qry:querySd2(1)                  , label:"No Param2"                          , retval:querySd2(1).sd_expires } ,
    {qry:querySd2(sd_code = "PickMe") , label:"No Param1 (CF2018+ (named params))" , retval:querySd2(sd_code = "PickMe").sd_expires } ,
    {qry:querySd2()                   , label:"No Params"                          , retval:querySd2().sd_expires } ,
    {qry:querySd2(1," ")              , label:"Edge. Empty string."                , retval:querySd2(1," ").sd_expires } 
] ;
//// Note that the above retval:querySd2().sd_expires only outputs one row. Loop
//// through the results themselves to output the multiple rows. 

writeDump(tests) ;
</cfscript>
```

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=32c93137-adb1-4f58-8ed4-21bb9e5212b2/ee3d9cac-e25e-46ca-8eec-f4ac8ddd4b41/4d295400-65fa-4b76-a889-a97a805409ea.cfm

***NOTE:** `queryExecute()` was added in CF11. Safe-navigation (`?.`) added in CF2016.*

**EDIT:** I changed my Mockaroo data to static query data. Apparently you can run through Mockaroo data pretty quickly. :-)

Comment: Well that didn't take long to blow through my Mockaroo allowance for the day. When I get home, I'll move the .csv somewhere that I can host it from an HTTPS connection.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful!  Adobe's documentation can be so lacking or not-user friendly at times.  There's a git page out there of cfquery examples in cfscript - your example should be added to that.

Comment: @Steve Hit up CFDocs if you're looking for function info. It's a little easier to navigate than some of the Adobe docs. Best source of info about CF is Google. There are tons of good bloggers who have written about good things. You just have to watch out for dated info. Unfortunately there's a lot of it. And, as a web dev, I would highly recommend becoming familiar with the stuff you can find on OWASP (https://www.owasp.org), especially their Top 10 info. But definitely Big Kudos for looking at cfscript over tags. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can place the part of the query in a variable and use it inside the query string.

```
local.queryPart = '';
if( isDefined('arguments.sd_id') ){
    local.queryPart &= ' AND sd_id = :sdid ';
};
if( isDefined('arguments.sd_code') ){
    local.queryPart &= ' AND sd_code = :sdcode ';
};
local.querySd.setSql('
    SELECT sd_id, sd_code, sd_active, sd_expires, sd_added, sd_dla
    FROM sd
    WHERE 0 = 0
    #local.queryPart#
');
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up creating a query string and building that up outside of the setSql().

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ternary operators:

```
local.querySd.setSql('
        SELECT sd_id, sd_code, sd_active, sd_expires, sd_added, sd_dla
          FROM sd
         WHERE 0 = 0
         # !isNull( arguments.sd_id ) ? ' AND sd_id = :sdid' : '' #
         # !isNull( arguments.sd_code ) ? ' AND sd_code = :sdcode' : '' #
    ');
```

Personally, I find this much more readable.

Comment: I don’t know why someone voted this answer down. I use ternary operators all the time in string construction, and they work perfectly fine in query construction. I voted this up.

Comment: I think it is more readable, but I don't like this string logic inside of of a query string. No upvote or downvote for me.